# Random replace items between lists

Tags: python, list, random, replace

I Have 2 Lists of data `list_A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]` and `list_B = [1,11,35,48,19]`.I have tow types of  questions.
number 1: how can I replace randomly tow items form `list_B` with `list_A` for 200 iterations and 200 lists created must be unique. for example `List_1 = [**2**,11,35,48,**42**]`
number 2: how can I replace first tow items of `list_B` and randomly select from `list_A` for example `list_2 = [**5**,**33**,35,48,19]`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

```
import random

list_A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]
list_B = [1,11,35,48,19]

x = random.randrange(0,5)
i = list_A[x]
list_A[x] = list_B[x]
list_B[x] = i

print(list_A)
print(list_B)
```

2. 

```
import random

list_A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]
list_B = [1,11,35,48,19]

x = random.randrange(0,7)
list_B[0] = list_A[x]
list_A.remove(list_A[x])
x = random.randrange(0,6)
list_B[1] = list_A[x]
print(list_B)
```

As Subhashis Pandey said, this is not the place for questions like these.